# Spectra Plus wav files not correct duration

Tags: recording, hydrophone

[image: SpectraPlus Image]I'm not sure if this is an issue with SpectraPlus or something else, but I heard others had similar problems with different software. I record with two hydrophones with a soundcard + monitoring it real-time on a laptop. Everything looks accurate and fine real-time, and the duration right on the spectrogram was correct, however, the wav file duration was around half what it should be. For example, If we recorded for 10 minutes, the final time on the spectrogram would show up properly, but the wav file would be 5 minutes. That wav file duration is progressing through the file at the top of the screen, but much slower (as if it thinks a second is longer than it actually is). Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry Maya, but the question is missing some basic information. You record with SpectraPlus, that's OK, but when you play the Wav file, what do you use? Again SpectraPlus? If so, did you try another wav player? Could you try Audacity?  Reason is: is recording faulty or is it playing sound?

Comment: Welcome, Maya! Your question is very relevant, but as @WMXZ mentioned, additional background information will help with problem-solving. Please provide your hardware/software methods (with as much relevant detail as you can)-- including recording setup and analysis methods. Please include basic settings as well (sample rate, etc). Then describe what you expect to see, and what you actually do see. These questions/answers will be useful for others with similar problems, so thorough description will help for future questions as well. Thanks!!

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response! @WMXZ! I typically use SpectraPlus to play back the recording. I checked and it seems to open up and play in Audacity fine, but the duration of the overall recording is still too short, the same problem as in SpectraPlus

Comment: For the wav files it's recording with my laptop through SpectraPlus on recorder mode, connected to SpectraPlus's sound card, and I have 2 hydrophones connected to that. I'm able to start/stop and monitor the recording real-time. After recording, the wav file saves to my desktop. I can open the file back up in SpectraPlus in post-processing mode. The data is already calibrated through the sound card.
Sampling rate - 96000 hz, FFT size - 1024
If I'm recording for 10 minutes, I would expect to see a file that is 10 minutes long, but the file size only shows as roughly 5 minutes long.

Comment: Two questions: when you record not via sound card but from PC mic does it work correctly? I just tried it and (on 30day free version) and obviously it works correctly. therefore 2nd question: is the soundcard setting consistent with SpectraPlus? Can you provide the (verified) settings of both soundcard and SpectraPlus?